# How to set initial ViewController from AppDelegate programmatically?

Tags: cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

As my question I got stuck in this point. Actually my problem is, in my sample I have to show login screen on start of app if user logged with his/her credentials successfully he/her will redirect to Home screen. If user open app second time I have to show Home screen as he already logged in.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Store flag "LoggedIn" in your app preferences and navigate based on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to prevent cocoa from loading an initial controller by opening your storyboard, selecting your window controller, and in the attributes inspector unchecking "Is Initial Controller"

Then something like this:

```
    NSWindowController controller;
    public override void DidFinishLaunching (NSNotification notification)
    {
        var storyboard = NSStoryboard.FromName ("Main", null);
        if (true)
            controller = (NSWindowController)storyboard.InstantiateControllerWithIdentifier ("FirstController");
        else
            controller = (NSWindowController)storyboard.InstantiateControllerWithIdentifier ("SecondController");
        controller.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront (this);          
    }
```

with FirstController and SecondController being the identifiers of two NSWindowControllers in your main storyboard.

Comment: Thank you so much , i will make a try

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{

        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        // If you have defined a root view controller, set it here:
    if(LoggedIn)
                window.RootViewController = new MainController();
    else
                window.RootViewController = new LoginController();

        // make the window visible
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();


    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response i am not doing sample in xamarin.ios in my AppDelegate didn't showing RootViewController option :( here is my code public override void DidFinishLaunching(NSNotificationnotification)
 {
     if(isAlreadyLoggedIn)
        {
            this. //not showing option “window” & “RootViewController”
        }
        else
        {
  
        }
 }